# Getting android key hash for trigger.io facebook module

Tags: android, facebook, trigger.io

In the trigger.io documentation for their Facebook module it has a "Tip" for getting your Android key hash to upload to Facebook:

> On Android a hash of the key used to sign your app is required by Facebook to confirm your app should be allowed to access the Facebook API. The easiest way to configure this is to simply start using the Facebook API, any API methods will return an error message which includes the hash and the URL to visit to configure it.

Is there any example code that should generate this error containing the hash? Or another way to get the hash?

I've been able to get an authentication error if I install the Facebook app onto the simulator but it doesn't return back the key hash.

I have looked at the official Android docs but it looks like there should be a file called `~/.android/debug.keystore` but trigger.io must be putting this file in a different place (or hosting it on their end for the remote build).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should see the hash needed in the log output when running the app through the Toolkit, I don't think it makes it to the error callback as it is directly logged out by the Facebook SDK (the docs could definitely be clearer about that).

If you want to get your hands directly on the keystore the toolkit uses you can find it in `.template/lib/debug.keystore` in your apps folder, you can also specify your own keystore in the local settings tab in the Toolkit.

Comment: I'm not seeing it even in the debug output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gdKQps7J

Comment: Using the instructions from Facebook's Android Tutorial with myApp/.template/lib/debug.keystore to get the hash key worked though!

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't getting the hash logged either until I tried putting a bogus hash key in my Facebook application settings.

After I did that I added this error callback to my login function:

```
function (err) {
  forge.logging.info(err);
}
```

And then Facebook said that my hash didn't match the one provided by my app and gave me the correct hash in the log.

Answer (score 1):

Trigger.io has introduced the new `forge.facebook.getKeyHash(success, error)` method to help easily get the Key Hash programatically. The new method is available in [Facebook Module v2.11 and above](https://trigger.io/modules/facebook/current/versions/).

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Trigger.io app directory and run `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .template/lib/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

If you're prompted for the keystore password, don't input anything, just hit Enter.